# Debugging application-embedded Lua code on Windows CE

Tags: debugging, lua, windows-ce

There are several tools for debugging Lua code like Luaedit or ZeroBrane, but I couldn't find any tool that is capable of debugging Lua code that is embedded on a Windows CE application.

For example, ZeroBrane requires luasocket to be available, as well as other things, and I can't find a Windows CE implementation for this library.

So are there tools for debugging Lua on Windows CE ?

Answer (score 0):

There is at least one [report of luasocket running on WinCE](http://lua-users.org/lists/lua-l/2011-10/msg00390.html). You may want to contact the author as if you get it running, you can use those tools you mentioned.

Another option is to try a [command-line debugger](https://github.com/slembcke/debugger.lua), as it doesn't require a socket library.